# Logging in to VirtualBox via SSH

Tags: networking

I'm starting with VirtualBox and Linux on a Windows machine. I can log in to Linux using the Virtual Box command line but I want to do something pretty easy: log in from an external (not virtualbox) command line to Linux using ssh. I've created a user hsander to do so: `ssh hsander@10.0.2.15` but: I get the message: Connection timed out

To do so I looked for my Linux ipaddress using: `/sbin/ifconfig -a` I get the following:

[image]

Normally the IP is shown next to "inet addr:...." but I think 10.0.2.15 is a pretty rare IP isn't?

So what am I doing wrong?

I've been searching on Google but yet no solutions...

Comment: Tell us what OS you are using for the Virtual machine. Is the `ssh` service running? Is there a firewall preventing you from logging to the machine? Can you ping the machine.. and so on.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That IP is likely inside a NAT block which VirtualBox has set up. You need to either bridge or forward if you want to access the machine's ports from outside; you can do both from the virtual machine settings panel.

Comment: Awesome! I changed the VirtualBox set up to bridged adapter and now I'm able to log in using ssh, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`connection timed out` means that the program sent a SYN packet (start of a TCP connection) but never got a response.

Most common causes are a faulty network connection (I think we can safely rule that one out) or a firewall that silently drops the packets somewhere between the source and destination.

NOTE: I can't speak to whether there is an SSH daemon running on the virtualbox, but if the connection were fine and there simply wasn't one running you'd get a `connection refused` instead as the server sends an immediate RST packet back to signify that there's nobody listening on that port.